# Updating parent entity when child entity is added (Greendao)

Tags: android, one-to-many, greendao

I am using greendao in my android app and an Activity that needs to refresh some item in a listview.

I have an entity "activity" that has an one-to-many relation to "exports"

In order to update the "activity" when a new "exports" is added I do as described in http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/relations/#Resolving_and_Updating_To-Many_Relations

```
Exports ex = new Exports();
ex.setActivityId(activityEntry.getId());
//DOING something...
exportsDao.insert(ex);
List<Exports> exportList = activityEntry.getExportsList();
exportList.add(ex);
```

This however gives me an java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:404)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Just came across this same issue -- You probably have this fixed by now but this is for reference for any recent users (as of Apr.25 2016)

The bugfix was fixed recently (early this year) as shown here

https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/issues/287
https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/pull/288

Judging from the above, if anyone has the same issue, the problem is most likely one of the following

1. You don't have the most recent greendao dependency version (which was prior to the recent fix)
2. Or you were like me and pulled the greendao project from github and mindlessly copied the gradle dependency version from the README file -- which looks like the following

   ```
   compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:2.1.0'
   ```

   which looks different from the gradle dependency on the official website.

   ```
   compile 'org.greenrobot:greendao:2.2.0'
   ```

Answer (score 0):

From the page you referenced, you have done the steps out of order.  Follow the steps in this order and see if it addresses the problem.

> This is how to insert new entities that are part of a to-many
>   relation:
>
> 1. Get the to-many Java List (This has to be done this before
>      persisting the new entity, because we do not know if we get a cached
>      for fresh result. Like this, we know it’s cached now.)
> 2. Create a new entity object (on the many side)
> 3. Set the foreign property of the new entity to the target entity
> 4. Persist the new object using insert
> 5. Add the new object to the to-many Java List

Comment: I tried exactly this. But I still end up with the exception?

             List<Exports> exportList = uploadSportActivityEntry.getExportsList();
                    Exports ex = new Exports();
                    ex.setActivityId(uploadSportActivityEntry.getId());
                    ex.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    ex.setUploader(getString(R.string.garminuploadkey));
                    exportsDao.insert(ex);
                    exportList.add(ex);